# ObjectStateManager vs Entry().State

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

What is the difference between this two and which is preferred? using change object state or `Entry().state`

```
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(employeeFromDB, EntityState.Modified)
```

vs

```
context.Entry(employeeFromDB).State = EnitityState.Modified;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you are invoking a function on the underlying `System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager` of your DbContext class to change a Property vs retrieving and changing it directly via the DbContext.

In the first example `ChangeObjectState()` can only be used to modify an `ObjectStateEntry` of an entity that already exists within the context. If you try to modify something that doesn't exist you'll get an exception thrown.

Check Exceptions in [ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.changeobjectstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

In the second example if the object doesn't exist in the context it gets added, you'll still get an exception when you call `db.saveChanges()` but the same approach could be used to add a new record just by changing `EntityState.Modified` to `EntityState.Added`

You'll also need to grab the underlying ObjectContext from your DbContext using `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext`